# 'border' makes 'background-color' works different

Tags: html, css, border, margin

This question seems not so significant as others but I'd like to **understand** **how** it works and **why** it works this way.

We have a very simple code pen here:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* border: 3px solid pink; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <h2>Subheader</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When border is commented the pen works like this:

[image: margins not colored]

We can see that `h1` and `h2` margins are not colored by property 'background-color'. Here I thought that 'ok, it's because it's only what `div.header` contains.

But if we are removing comments and make a border for `div.header` it suddenly becomes behave different.
[image: margins have been colored by border]

Now `h1` and `h2` margins became a part of `div.header` though border is only thing that changed. Can you help me explain this phenomenon. I know this has a logical explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The border doesn't have any (direct) effect on the background colour, it has an effect on the *margins*.

Without a border, the top and bottom margins of the child elements collapse through the edge of the element.

When you add a border, those margins stop at the border pushing the child elements away from it and increasing the size of the element inside the border (which is filled with the background colour).

See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/) for further reading.