# Why isn't the background applied to child element's margin?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="background-color: #666">
    <div style="margin: 20px">Some Content - no border</div>
</div>
```

However, if I add a border, background color is applied to the whole content including child element's margin:

```html
<div style="background-color: #666; border: 1px solid">
    <div style="margin: 20px">Some Content - has border</div>
</div>
```

What's the reason for this behavior? What's the specification explains this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['border' makes 'background-color' works different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821527/border-makes-background-color-works-different)

Comment: Thans @nullptr. Yes, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent Div is Empty, and the Child should have a distance to the border of the parent element, no background is shown in the margin. If you use Padding or a Border, you extend the area of the Child element to that border.